# How to determine which plot is shown reactively

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

Here are two plots I want to show in the APP. In ui.r, I have one input(plot type) and one output(plot).

plot type input:

```
sidebarPanel(
             checkboxGroupInput("vo", 
                                label = "Visualization Object", 
                                choices = list("Polar Distance of VAR from nadir" = 1, 
                                               "Real Value of VAR" = 2 
                                ),
                                selected = c(1,2)
             )
           )
```

and the plot output:

```
fluidRow(
           column(6,
                  plotOutput(outputId="polar", width = "600px", height = "600px")
           ),
           column(6,
                  plotOutput(outputId="paral", width = "600px", height = "600px")
           )
         )
```

In server.r, I use this:

```
if(1%in%vo){
  output$polar <- renderPlot({
    # input$reset

    ap(whole_p[[ts$counter]])
  })}
  if(2%in%vo){
  output$paral <- renderPlot({
    # input$reset

    av(whole_v[[ts$counter2]])
  })}
```

So how can I change the server code to make it work as: when I select `Polar Distance of VAR from nadir`, then only plot `output$polar` is shown in the ui, and when select `Real Value of VAR`, only plot `output$paral` is shown in the ui. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use `conditionalPanel`

Comment: @warmoverflow 


              your idea is good. However, when I use:
    conditionalPanel(condition = "1%in%input.vo==T",
                                     plotOutput(outputId="polar", width = "600px",         height =         "600px"))

it doesn't work.

Comment: The condition should be Javascript, so `%in%` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution based on `conditionalPanel`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("vo", 
                           label = "Visualization Object", 
                           choices = list("Polar Distance of VAR from nadir" = 1, 
                                          "Real Value of VAR" = 2 
                           ),
                           selected = c(1,2)
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.vo.indexOf('1') >= 0", plotOutput(outputId="polar", width = "600px", height = "600px")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.vo.indexOf('2') >= 0", plotOutput(outputId="paral", width = "600px", height = "600px"))
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$polar <- renderPlot({
      plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
    })
    output$paral <- renderPlot({
      plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$hp)
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I changed it as your code. It still has a problem. Two plots are both hidden. So why?

Comment: You should double check your code. If you run my code exactly as is, it should be working. I have tested again.

Comment: thanks, I don't know how, but it seems I need to restart R to run it.